# What is written on my mug?

Tags: meaning, kanji

I was able to identify 弐 (alternative form of 二 used on legal documents, according to Jisho.org), but I still can't identify the others, in order to know what is written there

[image]

<sup>*[Full-size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXSGo.jpg)*</sup>

Answer (score 4):

The text on the right reads 有田焼 (Arita-yaki), which is porcelain produced in the Arita (Saga-ken) region.

The text on the left reads 弐峰, which is a particular maker of Arita-yaki, but I don't know how to read the name. Maybe Futamine?